# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. Origin is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, http, cors, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

EDIT: No JSONP! Yes i know CORS is handled by the server and Yes the server does support it. The issue is on my side.

I am trying to use MediaWiki API from the browser. I am sending a GET request through XMLHttpRequest but due to CORS issues it's just not working. I am getting the following message from my browser after it receives the response:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srsearch=Oculus&utf8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

I understand why i am getting this issue but i do not know how can i solve it from the browser/JavaScript side.

Code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + subreddit + "&utf8",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send();
```

Some of the things i've tried:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

and setting the parameter origin in the url or as setRequestHeader which returned a invalid/bad Origin, denied.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: add a callback-parameter and request the results in JSONP-format

Comment: _i do not know how can i solve it from the browser/JavaScript side_ CORS is set and controlled by the server.

Comment: to maybe clarify what @Dr.Molle suggested - you get jsonp from wikipedia by adding a (undocumented!) `callback=` parameter, in addition to `format=json` - and then read up on how to "do" jsonp successfully (i.e. you do not use XMLHttpRequest for instance)

Comment: So i get downvoted for asking a question that's valid? The "duplicate" question gives solutions such as using JSONP which is not what i want. Other answers say to set headers or are plainly wrong. To re-iterate i don't want to use JSONP. The best answer links to a blog that makes use of XDomainRequest() instead of XMLHttpRequest(). Upon comparison it seems that XDomainRequest() is needed instead for CORS compatibility.

Comment: `To re-iterate i don't want to use JSONP` - put that in the question, and then you may as well delete your question because you **can not** fix a "lack of CORS" issue client side

Comment: `XDomainRequest` is (old?) Internet Exploder specific - so, not much of a solution at all

Comment: Then none of the answers in that "duplicate" question are valid.

Comment: Yes they are, as you don't (or, didn't until just now) state your hesitance in using JSONP in your question

Comment: JSONP doesn't fix the issue, it just bypasses the CORS issue. MediaWiki supports CORS so i dont know why i'm getting this browser issue.

Comment: _MediaWiki supports CORS_ - what makes you say this?

Comment: nevermind - found it in the documentation, which you should read

Comment: i think this? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS and https://github.com/monsur/enable-cors.org/issues/55

edit: yes and i did try to set an origin parameter but it said it was refused.

Comment: what did you set it to? same as the Origin header I hope

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSONP.

```
<script src='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srsearch=Oculus&utf8&callback=callbackname'></script>
<script>
    function callbackname(data){
       //you can get response data here
    }
</script>
```

If you use jquery.

```
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srsearch=Oculus&utf8&callback=?', function(data){
    //you can get response data here
})
```

Comment: is there a none JSONP way of handling this CORS issue? From what i've read it seems like a hacky way of bypassing the issue without really addressing it.

Comment: the only CORS issue is that they don't issue CORS headers and you want them to

Comment: JSONP is also not a solution, as the callback parameter is not documented in their API

Comment: [CROS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) by  set http header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  on server.  Or add a Proxy api in your server to fetch data from anthor server.

Comment: i've done that it didn't work. i've tried setting up many http headers and none fixed the issue. edited code above as an example.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are expected in the response from the server which has CORS enabled. The server/host to which you're making this request should send those headers in the response, only then browser will accept and process the response received. Setting these `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in your request will not make it a CORS request :)

Comment: figured since it didn't work when i tried it even before it was mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS#Description), the `origin` parameter that you're passing in the request, and `Origin` header that is sent by your browser in the AJAX call should match and also it must match one of the values in `$wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains` on the foreign wiki. As your Origin  (http://127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000 in your case) won't be available in `$wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains`, MediaWiki API will never send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response and any CORS request will fail with the error that you're seeing in your browser's console.

Another important fact to consider is that

> MediaWiki API is used on Wikimedia sites to do things like allow image
>   uploads directly to Commons from Wikipedia sites on the mobile
>   interface.

This API is not for public consumption from any host, it's just for a set of validated hosts.

If you want to try some CORS requests, you can use GitHub API from [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/).
Here's a sample [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BopZZm?editors=101) making a CORS request to GitHub API and the JSON response is logged to DevTools Console.

Comment: But isn't the issue with CORS a security one that my browser implements? Why is there a server-side whitelist of origins for which CORS is allowed? From what i understand about CORS, my browser sends a request to A but the response is sent from B so it doesn't accept the response to be read. Am i misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: Nope. CORS is about cross-domain requests. A script from domain A cannot make an AJAX call to domain B because of Same Origin Policy. CORS relaxes this restriction so that domain A script can make a call to domain B but it's up to domain B to respond to that request. If B trusts A then it will send `Access-Contol-Allow-*` headers and browser can process the response. On the other hand, if B doesn't know A, it will not send CORS specific headers and the browser will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to do what you want because there is a server-side whitelist of origins for which CORS is allowed, and your server is not on the whitelist.

Currently there is no option in MediaWiki for auth-less CORS, so the whitelist is applied to all CORS requests, whether they include auth or not.

See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T62835 and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS

Comment: But isn't the issue with CORS a security one that my browser implements? Why is there a server-side whitelist of origins for which CORS is allowed? From what i understand about CORS, my browser sends a request to A but the response is sent from B so it doesn't accept the response to be read. Am i misunderstanding the issue?