# Cannot access Wikidata API

Tags: javascript, cors, mediawiki-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

I'm trying to use the Wikidata API, but all I'm getting is:

> Fetch API cannot load https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=Ingmar%20Bergman&language=en&limit=20&format=json&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dev.example.com%3A3000. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.dev.example.com:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is the code:

```
const headers = new Headers();

const origin = "http://www.dev.example.com:3000";
headers.append("Origin", origin);
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

const url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php";

const query = {
    action: "wbsearchentities",
    search: "Ingmar Bergman",
    language: "en",
    limit: 20,
    format: "json",
    origin
};

const myInit = new Request(url + "?" + qs.stringify(query), {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors-with-forced-preflight",
    headers
});

fetch(myInit)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I have tried JSONP as well, no success. Running the link in the browser (just without the origin parameter) gives a proper response.

Comment: CORS is currently only allowed from other Wikimedia domains. JSONP should work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32868530/323407) for more details.

Comment: Also please see https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T62835 which is a ticket entitled "Enable cross-domain API requests in API's JSON responses" which would likely help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why do you add the "origin" parameter at all? Just leave it off, or add "&callback=some_function" to get JSONP.

Comment: JSONP request did work after removing the origin parameter. Thank you.

Comment: In Firefox 121 JSONP I get blocked because of ``X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff``

Answer (score 2):

add origin=* to the querystring, e.g.

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&language=es&type=item&format=json&origin=*&search=Agav